Concrete mathematics page 11 (The Josephus Problem - Proof)
Can someone check my proof for the odd case of the recurrence relation for the Josephus problem from Concrete Mathematics, Chapter 1, page 11

Our recursive equation:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    J(1) &= 1 \\ 
    J(2n) &= 2J(n)-1, \quad \text{for } n\ge 1;\\
    J(2n+1) &= 2J(n)+1, \quad \text{for }n\ge 1.\\
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
recurrence solution
\begin{equation}
  J(2^m+l)=2l+1, \quad \text{ for } m \ge 0 \text{ and } 0\le l< 2^m.   
\end{equation}
First lets prove the basis case if $m=0$ and $l=0$;
we get our basis of  $J(1)=1$, which is now proven true.
Next proving by induction
we start with the recursive equation for the even case:
\begin{equation*}
J(2n) = 2J(n) - 1, \quad \text{ for } n \geq 1
\end{equation*}
We want to show that when $n = 2^m + l$, where $l$ is even,
the equation holds for the closed-form solution $J(2^m + l) = 2l + 1$.
Substituting $n = 2^m + l$ into the recursive equation, we get:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split} 
J(2^m + l) &= 2J\left(\frac{2^m + l}{2}\right) - 1 \\
&= 2J\left(2^{m-1} + \frac{l}{2}\right) - 1 \quad (\text{since } l \text{ is even})
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Now, we want to use our inductive hypothesis that the closed-form solution holds
for $J(2^{m-1} + l/2)$.
So, we substitute $J(2^{m-1} + l/2) = 2\left(\frac{l}{2}\right) + 1$ into the equation:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split} 
J(2^m + l) &= 2\left[2\left(\frac{l}{2}\right) + 1\right] - 1 \\
&= 4\left(\frac{l}{2}\right) + 2 - 1 \\
&= 2l + 1
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
which is what we want from (1.5) and our inductive hypothesis. This proof also works
for our odd case,
when $2^m+l=2n+1$.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split} 
J(2^m + l) &= 2J\left(\frac{2^m + l-1}{2}\right) - 1 \\
&= 2J\left(2^{m-1} + \frac{l-1}{2}\right) - 1 \quad (\text{since } l \text{ is odd})
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Now, we want to use our inductive hypothesis that the closed-form solution holds
for $J(2^{m-1} + (l-1)/2)$.
So, we substitute $J(2^{m-1} + (l-1)/2) = 2\left(\frac{l-1}{2}\right) + 1$ into the equation:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split} 
J(2^m + l) &= 2\left[2\left(\frac{l-1}{2}\right) + 1\right] - 1 \\
&= 4\left(\frac{l-1}{2}\right) + 2 - 1 \\
&= 2l - 1
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Found the error
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
J(2^m + l) &= 2\left[2\left(\frac{l-1}{2}\right) + 1\right]+ 1 \
&= 2\left(l-1+1\right)  + 1 \
&= 2l + 1
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
thats the proof
